# PHP - Inconsistency with "Undefined offset" error

Tags: php, arrays, undefined, offset

Why does PHP throw a "Notice: Undefined offset" error here:

```
<?php
$MyVar = array();
echo $MyVar[0]; //Notice: Undefined offset: 0
?>
```

But not here:

```
<?php
$MyVar = false;
echo $MyVar[0]; //No error
?>
```

Comment: It is due to the variable type. Since an array has an offset, but a boolean value does not, an offset is not undefined, instead it is simply `NULL`. The same offset notice applies to strings `$MyVar = ''; echo $MyVar[0];` Which would result in `Uninitialized string offset: 0`

Comment: @fyrye me attempting to reference an offset of a boolean should be even more of a reason to throw an error/warning/notice

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-55 `Accessing variables of other types (not including arrays or objects implementing the appropriate interfaces) using [] or {} silently returns NULL.` This implies that PHP expects you to verify the variable type prior to accessing it with `[]` or `{}` e.g. `if (is_array($MyVar))`

Comment: @fyrye put that in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

It's ultimately because in your 2nd example `$MyVar[0]` is null which isn't an error. You could probably reference `$MyVar[0][1][2][3]` and get the same result.

The first example isn't null it's a missing index in an array so it warns you.

Comment: The first example does in fact echo NULL, but also throws an error. Try the first example and you'll see "Notice: Undefined offset" followed by "NULL"

Comment: That does make sense as PHP specifically looks out for undefined indexes. Note it's not an error but a notice.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined offset is provided when there are no values in an array and you're trying to reference an uninitialised index.

In case of the 2nd code, you've assigned(initialised) a value to the variable which is not different from variable[0].

If you assign values for 1st two indexes in 1st example, and refer to the 3rd index, you should get the undefined offset error.

I dont think it is about null or not, but a case of assigning values to indexes.
If you take a C parlance, array is an equivalent of malloc(upto a certain extent). Thankfully PHP does not crash, just throws an undefined index[offset] error